# Spring REST API - User + his profile persist

Tags: java, spring, rest

I made an POST mapping `myapp.com/users` in my Spring App. When I send data to this mapping, I need create `User` and his `Profile`. Relation between them is `OneToOne`. Example:

AbstractEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
}
```

User: (Only important stuff)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User extends AbstractEntity {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Profile profile;

    public Profile getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }
}
```

Profile: (Only important stuff)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Profiles")
public class Profile extends AbstractEntity {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user;
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

And my RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    /**
     * Registers a new user.
     *
     * @param user User data
     */
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> register(@RequestBody User user) {
        try {
            userService.persist(user);
            LOG.debug("User {} successfully registered.", user);
            final HttpHeaders headers = RestUtils.createLocationHeaderFromCurrentUri("/current");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
        catch (TransactionSystemException e) {
            throw new PersistenceException(e.getOriginalException());
        }
    }
}
```

How can I send both User and Profile? `@RequestBody` can receive only one Entity what I know. I tried this JSON data:

```
{
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "1234",
    "profile":{
        "name": "User",
        "surname": "Test"
    }
}
```

But even User and Profile are created, there is no relation between them (USER_ID not set).

Here are the table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `BIRTHDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `DESCRIPTION` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GENDER` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IMAGE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `SURNAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `USER_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `sequence` (
  `SEQ_NAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `SEQ_COUNT` decimal(38,0) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `sequence` (`SEQ_NAME`, `SEQ_COUNT`) VALUES
('SEQ_GEN', '50');

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `BLOCKED` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `EMAIL` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ROLE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `USERNAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `profiles`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `FK_profiles_USER_ID` (`USER_ID`);

ALTER TABLE `sequence`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`SEQ_NAME`);

ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `EMAIL` (`EMAIL`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `USERNAME` (`USERNAME`);

ALTER TABLE `profiles`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_profiles_USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `users` (`ID`);
```

Comment: Your entities, as posted, don't have any ID. Post the relevant code. Also post the table definitions.

Comment: Database tables are created automatically from Entites (I think JPA doing it?). I edited post. I have AbstractEntity what have id, and its used on all other entities.

Comment: Tell what your database is, and post the table definitions. I don't see how a profile could exist in the database without any profile id. A primary key shouldn't be nullable.

Comment: I edited post! I have `private Integer id;` derived from `AbstractEntity`

Comment: Also my database is MySQL. I always build war and move it into Tomcat. Tables are created automatically.

Comment: The fact that tables are created automatically shouldn't prevent you from posting how they are defined. Post the table definitions.

Comment: @JBNizet https://pastebin.com/8G5SAyeQ

Comment: There should be a profile_id foreign key in users. There shouldn't be any user_id column in profiles. I doubt these tables have been generated by Hibernate, and I doubt this code has generated anything in thse tables. BTW, your question says PROFILE_ID is not set, but there is no PROFILE_ID column in what you posted.

Comment: @JBNizet I edited code by `AlexandruSabou's` answer. Now I only have USER_ID

Comment: Since the answer tells you to make Profile the owner os the association, and to move the foreign key in profile, you need to change your code and to set the profile's user, in addition to setting the user's profile.

Comment: I changed annotations from User to Profile and from Profile to User and now it works. User is created, then Profile, then User's PROFILE_ID is set to Profile's id.

Comment: Additional question: Is possible to have USER_ID set on Profile too? So it will be bidirectional?

Comment: So you went back to what it was before, and now it works fine. No, it's not possible, and you don't need nor want that. You already have a bidirectional association between User and Profile, and it works fine with just one foreign key. No need to add a second one: it would be redundant.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have an attribute annotated with **@Id**.
You have to add the mappedBy to the owner of the relationship, in your case **User**. Try the following modifications

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User extends AbstractEntity {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    //Edited here
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Profile profile;

    public Profile getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Profiles")
public class Profile extends AbstractEntity {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    //Edited here
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private User user;
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Both `User` line and `Profile` line were created, but profile's column `USER_ID` is NULL :(

Comment: @OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private User user;

Comment: Still NULL. Maybe I need to use different way of JSON data? Or different way of persisting

Comment: I changed annotations from User to Profile and from Profile to User and now it works. User is created, then Profile, then User's PROFILE_ID is set to Profile's id.

Comment: Great. Good job.